# Fetch records from multiple tables in SQL Server - tricky

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables (Application,Transaction).

Application

```
 ID      ApplicationName TransactionID
 -------------------------------------
 1             A             100
 2             A             101 
 3             B             102
 4             B             103
```

- `TransactionID` is unique.
- Application can have multiple TransactionID's.

Transaction

```
ID      TransactionID   RequestNumber
---------------------------------------
 1            100           RQ1000
 2            101           RQ1000
 3            102           RQ1001
 4            102           RQ1001
 5            102           RQ1002
```

- Single `TransactionID` can have multiple `RequestNumber`
- Multple `TransactionID` can have same `RequestNumber`

Now my question is: I want to retrieve data it should be like below

```
ApplicationName  Count(RequestNumber)  RequestNumberList
--------------------------------------------------------
      A                 1                   RQ1000
      B                 2                   RQ1001,RQ1002
```

- `Count(RequestNumber)` should be distinct `RequestNumber` for that application
- `RequestNumberList` should be distinct `RequestNumber` which is comma separated

I can get required result without 3rd column using below query:

```
SELECT 
    ApplicationName, COUNT(DISTINCT RequestNumber) AS RequestNumber_Count
FROM 
    Application A
JOIN 
    Transaction T ON A.TransactionID = T.TransactionID
GROUP BY 
    ApplicationName
```

Result:

```
ApplicationName  Count(RequestNumber)
-------------------------------------
      A                 1
      B                 2
```

With 3rd column I wrote like this:

```
SELECT 
    ApplicationName, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT RequestNumber) AS RequestNumber_Count,
    COALESCE(RequestNumber + ', ', '')
FROM 
    Application A
JOIN 
    Transaction T ON A.TransactionID = T.TransactionID
GROUP BY 
    ApplicationName, RequestNumber
```

Result:

```
ApplicationName  Count(RequestNumber)  RequestNumberList
---------------------------------------------------------
      A                 1                   RQ1000,
      B                 1                   RQ1001,
      B                 1                   RQ1002,
```

I need alteration to my 2nd query to get desired result

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been asked and answered dozens and dozens of times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Comment: I have query to fetch either of 2nd or 3rd column not both in same query..There is a difference between other question and this question..please check

Comment: No...it is the exact same concept. Start with your first query that gets everything else. The using STUFF and FOR XML you will generate the comma delimited list just like the duplicate question.

Comment: In the link you given.They are fetching multiple project ID's for the same employee.It can be achieved easily by using COALESCE.
In my example I have two tables I wants to map Each application has how many distinct Request number with those request number in 2 tables with TransactionID as reference.
When you use COALESCE or STUFF you should use both ApplicationName and RequestNumber in GroupBy this in turn won't produce desired result.

Comment: I tried using STUFF ...it's throwing error RequestNumber is not a part of aggregate function.

Comment: Can you share what you tried? I don't have time to wrestle with this today but I can probably help you with this tomorrow.

Comment: Finally Achieved with the combination of GROUP BY,HAVING and STUFF CLAUSE.

Comment: Thank you, Sean Lange for your support and concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally Achieved with the combination of JOIN,STUFF,GROUP BY and HAVING clause.**

`SELECT A.ApplicationName,COUNT(DISTINCT T.RequestNumber) AS RequestNumber_Count,
RequestNumberList = STUFF((
          SELECT  ',' +B.RequestNumber
          FROM Application D
          JOIN 
          Trnsaction B 
          ON  D.TransactionID=B.TransactionID
          GROUP BY D.ApplicationName,B.RequestNumber
          HAVING D.ApplicationName=A.ApplicationName
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM Application A
JOIN 
Trnsaction T 
ON  A.TransactionID=T.TransactionID
GROUP BY A.ApplicationName`